# android, text retrieved from webservices

Tags: android

My problem is all the texts comes from webservices. So, at the beginning, I call the webservice and I have to set the texts in strings.xml. I know writing in strings.xml it's impossible but we had the same problem on iOs and a solution has been found here http://iosapplove.com/archive/2013/01/localizable-strings-how-to-load-translations-dynamically-and-use-it-inside-your-iphone-app/.

So my question is : Is there a similar way on android ? (I think no)

It exists alternative way like using database or sharedPreferences but these solutions won't be very effective. Moreover, the application will contain many languages.

So my second question : What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: are you really sure you can't integrate the texts in the application?

Comment: Yes. It's a request from customer

Comment: If you retrieve them from net, what is a problem to store them as a text file? If you don't want to use database or shared preferences.

Comment: I'm not against using database or sharedPreference but I'm afraid of perf impact ...

Comment: yeah, this sounds like a terrible idea...

Comment: do you know estimately like how many strings your app will contain for one language? 100? 1000?

Comment: I had faced the same situation in one of my project.i chose to store it as properties file... and then accessed it from properties file...it is simpler.. and i never faced an issue with that project.

Comment: I have approximatively 400 texts ! (x2 because in a first version, there will be two languages and more in a second version)

Comment: @amal How many text in your app ? Multiple languages ?

Comment: @aat i had some 200 texts and three languages..three different files come in... i stored them to respective properties file... (this is way i chose.. i am not sure whether its the best way)

Comment: @amal Can you post a piece of code, please ? I think, I'm going to test this solution.

Comment: i dont think i will be able to help you with the whole code ... but if you want i can post some code on reading and writing properties file..

Comment: If you can post some code, it's cool. I've never used properties files, so if I can have some code, it's perfect otherwise I will google :)

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, the strings.xml files will not exist in the APK. This means that there is no way to change what getResources().getString(R.string.mystring) will return.

You say that "it's a request from customer". My suggestion is that you tell the customer "this is a bad idea". Because it really is.

If the customer persists I guess your only option is to download the texts in whatever language it is that you need and store it in your apps external file storage. The suggestion to use a [properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html) file is good. [Load it as an InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [get strings from it](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Have you considered what will happen if the app is in flight mode or does not have a network available when started? Will you provide default values?

Also, with this solution you will not be able to set any texts in TextViews or similar in XML since the system won't have access to your downloaded translations in the properties files.

If you still go ahead with this I'd also suggest that you wrap the Properties file into some other class and fall back to whatever texts you have in your strings.xml if a text doesn't exist in the properties file or if it wasn't downloaded for some reason:

```
class TextRetriever {

    // the downloaded texts go here
    private Properties properties;

    private Context context;

    public String getString(String key) {
        String s = properties.getProperty(key);
        // not found in properties file
        if(s == null) {
            // fall back to value in strings.xml
            s = context.getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", context.getPackageName())
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```